# Remove file at path Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am learning to build API by myself. I was wondering how to delete a file that stored physical hard drive. I have read a post that I can use `fs.unlink` for this job. In order to that, I need a path.

First of all, this is my file structure:

```
root_folder
        ->api (folder)
             -> models (folder)
                      -> product.js

             -> route (folder)
                      -> products.js
        ->node_modules
        ->uploads (image folder)
        ->app.js (main js file)
        ->nodemon.json
        ->package.json
        ->package-lock.json
        ->server.js
```

These are my model & route files:

*product.js* (model file)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
     _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     name: {type: String, require: true},
     price: {type: Number, require: true},
     productImage: {type: String, require: true}
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

*products.js* (route file)

```
router.delete('/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.productId;
Product.deleteOne({_id: id})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Product Deleted' + test,
            request: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/', 
                body: {name: 'String', price: 'Number', productImage: 'String'}
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            err: err
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Stored data as an example:

```
{
    "product": {
         "_id": "5b8699c02c457856d08a2084",
         "name": "asdasdasd",
         "price": 12.1,
         "productImage": "uploads\\1535547840473pp.png"
    },
    "request": {
         "type": "GET",
         "url": "http://localhost:3000/products/5b8699c02c457856d08a2084"
    }

}
```

Here, it is my question. I want to access the file path that I uploaded. I am holding the path in `productImage`. As I wrote, I could not access. How can I do it because I want to delete the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help of @ArtemArkhipov in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162032/type-error-cannot-read-property-imagename-of-undefined?noredirect=1#comment91274249_52162032) the real solution while getting the path and deleting both entry and physical stored file.

```
Router.delete('/:productId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  var imageName = "";

  Product.findById(id)
    .select('productImage')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      imageName = docs.productImage;
      fs.unlinkSync(__rootdir + "\\" + imageName);
      console.log(docs.productImage); // by the way you had misspell here
      return Product.deleteOne({_id: id}).exec();
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Product Deleted',
        request: {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/',
          body: {
            name: 'String',
            price: 'Number',
            productImage: 'String'
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```