# Type Error: Cannot Read Property 'imageName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I practice building restful API with node.js with using MongoDB. I have a router that sends delete request `router.delete`. Inside of the `router.delete` I have two operations. First one is to find and select `productImage`according to given id, and with using `fs.unlinkSync` delete the uploaded file in the physical hard drive. Second one is that delete the database entry according to id.
if I do like that, I got an error, and I just delete the database entry.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'productImage' of null at Product.findById.select.exec.then.docs

If I create two different `route.delete`, I just could operate physical deletion. How can I do it both operation at the same time?

Here, This is my code:

```
Router.delete('/:productId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.productId;
var imageName = "";

Product.findById(id)
    .select('productImage')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        imageName = docs.productImage;
        fs.unlinkSync(__rootdir + "\\" + imageName);
        console.log(doc.productImage);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });

Product.deleteOne({_id: id})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Product Deleted',
            request: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/', 
                body: {name: 'String', price: 'Number', productImage: 'String'}
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Seems document is already deleted when you trying to get it from db. Why didn't you call delete operation after document was found and unlink started?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov first of all, I defined the `productImage` as a string, so I am holding the path. Is it affecting the data entry? let me try to commend the delete the entry operation, and let you know

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov the part that starts with `Product.findbyid` it is just delete the file that stored in physical hard drive. Path still parts in the `imageProduct`

Comment: Yes, but before it gets to '.then()'  it probably was deleted by deleteOne operation below. All functions are async, that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that document, which you are trying to find (and select some fields) is already deleted by second part of your code. (That is possible because all of these operations are asynchronous).
Not sure if it is the best solution, but I recommend you to remove document only after it was found and its 'productImage' was successfuly received and fs unlink started.

```
Router.delete('/:productId', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  var imageName = "";

  Product.findById(id)
    .select('productImage')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      imageName = docs.productImage;
      fs.unlinkSync(__rootdir + "\\" + imageName);
      console.log(docs.productImage); // by the way you had misspell here
      return Product.deleteOne({_id: id}).exec();
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Product Deleted',
        request: {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/products/',
          body: {
            name: 'String',
            price: 'Number',
            productImage: 'String'
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

P.S. I also recommend you not to use `unlinkSync` method, because synchronous operations are blocking thread. I would prefer using `fs.unlink` instead.

Comment: I will try it immediately.